# Unix script print arguments

Tags: bash, unix, arguments

I would like to print a few arguments given in the console
but I would like to print the argument with a number given from a integer

`declare -i I=2`
`declare -i I=4`

I would like to print the arguments number 2 and number 4 how can I do that
without using the following if statements

```
if [ $I -eq 2 ]; then
echo $2
fi
```

What I am searching for is somethink like this
`echo $($I) #first access $I, which is 4 and`
`# then print $4, which is the 4th argument`

Comment: `var -i I=2` is it valid in Unix shell scripts?

Comment: sorry meant `declare -i I=2`

Comment: Use indirect expansion: `echo "${!I}"`

Comment: Some bit of research helps.  This has been asked (and answered) scores of times on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for `variable indirection`. Use like this:

```
func() {
    p=4
    echo "${!p}"
}
```

**TESTING:**

```
func aa bb cc dd ee
dd
```

Answer (score 1):

To see what each argument is assigned to you can use this loop.

```
for n in $(seq 1 $#)
do
  echo $n ${!n}
done
```